# Preg_match can't figure it out

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to achieve the following:
I want to match specific numeric results that look like this 13245 or 12346.1 or 1243.25 or 0.52 which I somehow did this until now but it also passes numbers like this: 12542. (with the full stop at the end -.-")

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,}+[.,]{0,1}+[0-9]{0,2}$/", trim($num))) {
    print trim($num);
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas how I can fix this? I tried adding [^.] in the end but it doesn't seem to work or I am writing it wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/", trim($num))) {
    print trim($num);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! One small request though. Is it possible to be able to work with either . or , ? Thank you!

Comment: @user3465843: `/^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: Sure. If I am not getting you wrong, you want to match 1234,5 just like 1234.5. Then you need to replace `\.` with `[.,]` in the pattern

Comment: Awesome! Damn.. I stuck here like 2 hours and you solved it in 2 minutes -.-" Also thank you Sbls for the help too! I will accept the answer in 3 mins, won't let me do it earlier